# Use custom JavaScript function with Laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm having some trouble using custom JavaScript function within Laravel 5.6 and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a custom file created in **/assets/js/** labeled **helpers.js** with the following function:

```
export const isBetween = function(n, a, b) {
    return (n - a) * (n - b) <= 0
};
```

Then, in **app.js** I imported the file:

```
import { isBetween } from './helpers.js';
```

If I do **console.log(isBetween(20, 1, 40)** inside app.js, it works properly. However, I can't execute inside my blade template; the console log says it's not defined. E.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        console.log(isBetween(20, 1, 40));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use `import` in ES6/ES5 to import specific modules. But if you want to use it outside of your app.js, then you must make it a global variable like so:

`window.isBetween = isBetween; // add this in helpers.js`

Comment: Great, that solved my problem so I'll accept it as the answer, but I'm curious if this is the best practice for a Laravel application?

Comment: Well, it's perfectly fine to have global variables if you have 2 separate scripts (app.js and say another) that are interdependent. All you have to make sure is that they don't conflict with other JS scripts or libraries. Typically, well written libraries encapsulate most variables, so I dont think you will have to worry about this. But if you want to be `really` cautious you can namespace it like so: `window.myAppName = {}; window.myAppName.isBetween = isBetween` and in your JQuery use `myAppName.isBetween(....)`. That way all your global functions can share your app namespace

Answer (score 0):

If you're running mix in a terminal with `npm run watch` and you're still experiencing this issue then double check to make sure you're including the mix'd assets on your blade template:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Also, make sure that this `<script>` tag is *above* any of your other JS scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but yes, I am running npm run watch and app.js is above my other scripts. I am using <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> instead of mix(), but I tried that as well and didn't work.